# Getting ethernet cards info

Tags: linux, networking, slackware

I have 2 ethernet cards installed. The first one is onboard (integrated) the second is extra added PCI card installed in PCI2 slot. Is there any way (using a specific command) to detect which one belongs to eth0 and which to eth1? 
I'm running Slackware 14.

Answer (score 0):

The `lspci` command will give some information about your network card

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

or `lspci -vvv`

In your case `eth0` should be belongs to the integrated card

Answer (score 0):

The MAC address of the card is fixed (and the first three bytes identify the manufacturer). So you can tell which device is which by looking at the MAC address.

Commands for that are e.g. `ip link` or `ifconfig -a`.

You can also use udev rules to assign specific devices names based on the MAC address, so you'll know `eth:i` is the internal card, and `eth:e` the external one (or whatever names you choose). On Debian, `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` is responsible for that, I have no idea what Slackware does.